# python 3: im a beginner and i need to know what im missing. how do i make it state each childs name individually?

Tags: python, python-3.x, percentage

The program will allow the teacher to enter the number of students in her class, and enter the names of each student. Then she will be able to enter the results for one test and find out the percentage scores and a mean average for the class.

This is what I've got so far:

```
how=int(input("how many students in your class?"))
for i in range (how):
   student=str(input("Enter name of student " +str(i+1)+":"))
for n in range (how):
    score=int(input("Enter the score of child " +str(n+1)+":"))
outof=int(input("what was the exam out of?"))
print ("The percentage scores are:")
for p in range (how):
    print (student,":",(score/outof)*100,"%")
```

I want it to say each child and each percentage individually. I'd also like to work out the mean of the data.

Comment: You need to add each student's name and score to a `list` as they are entered.

Comment: http://www.diveintopython.net/native_data_types/lists.html

Comment: str(input()) is unnecessary as input() is already an str.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example

```
list_students = []
list_score = []
list_outof = []

how=int(input("how many students in your class?"))
for i in range(how):
   student=str(input("Enter name of student " +str(i+1)+":"))
   list_students.append(student)

for student in list_students:
    score=int(input(" " + student +":"))
    list_score.append(score)
    outof=int(input("what was the exam out of?"))
    list_outof.append(outof)

print("The percentage scores are:")
for index, student in enumerate(list_students):
    print (student,":",(list_score[index]/list_outof[index])*100.0,"%")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is rather simplistic but it should give you enough of a basis to build on for your project.

```
how = raw_input("how many students in your class?\n")#raw_input() always returns a string
how = int(how)
student_list = []
for student in range(how):
    x = raw_input("please input the student's name\n")
    y = raw_input("Type the student's score\n")
    y = int(y)
    student_list.append((x,y))#simple tuple with student's name and score
total =0
for each in student_list:
    total+= each[1]

print "The average was " +str(total/float(how))
```